# Create a {if} statement in WHMCS

Tags: if-statement, whmcs

Im trying to create a specific IF statement on the clientareaproductdetails.tpl file in WHMCS - bottom line i'm trying to display some text on a page depending on the product the customer is looking at.

So this is what I tried (which does not work)

```
{if $id  == '17'} something {else} nothing {/if}
```

So if the product ID = 17 then display 'something' otherwise display 'nothing.

Any ideas if/how this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

H

Answer (score 0):

If by product id, you mean the package id, then it explains why your code didn't work. $id variable is for service id.

To achieve what you want, Add a hook file (say: custom_product_message.php) to includes/hooks/ folder.

Then add the following code:

```
<?php
add_hook('ClientAreaProductDetailsOutput', 1, function($service) {
    if (!is_null($service)) {
        if ($service['service']->packageId == 17) {
            return "something";
        } else {
          return 'nothing';
        }
    }
    return '';
});
```

The idea is to use [ClientAreaProductDetailsOutput](https://developers.whmcs.com/hooks-reference/output/#clientareaproductdetailsoutput) hook to display a text in the clientarea productdetails page.